# Partial Notation in the Context of Maximum Modulus Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, notation

I was reading through the responses to this thread:

[$|f(z)|\le 1-|z|\forall z\in D$, we need to show $f\equiv 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287922/fz-le-1-z-forall-z-in-d-we-need-to-show-f-equiv-0)

and I noticed that in accepted answer, that response uses the notation $\partial B(0,r)$ in reference to the disk. I know that this notation comes from the Maximum Modulus Principle, and I was wondering what this partial notation meant in this context. Is this referring to the closure of a set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of topology, $\partial D$ denotes the [(topological) boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)) of $D$, i.e. the set of all points $z$ such that any neighborhood of $z$ intersects both $D$ and the complement of $D$.

One version of the maximum modulus principle can then be stated as follows:
If $D \subset \Bbb C$ is open and a function $f:\overline D \to \Bbb C$ is holomophic in $D$ and continuous in $\overline D$ then $f$ attains its maximum on $\partial D$.